# creating a translucent plastic material

Tags: three.js

I would like to create a plastic material using three.js, something like the lighter fuel container here:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Render/Import/SolidWorks
I would be glad if I could get a reasonably simple example to start working from.

I am actually not rendering an image but visualizing a mathematical problem (cellular automata). I need a set of interlocking surfaces (something like sheets of plastic foil) with as much visual information as possible, so I can distinguish between them. Therefore I was looking for: translucency, reflections, rotating an object with a fixed light source, visible edges. Later I will add some animated color coding, but for now I need a good material.

Here is the current status of my code:
https://github.com/jeras/three.js/tree/master/pyca

Here is how this networks look for 1D CA, but I would like to handle a 2D problem:
http://rattus.info/al/files/conference.pdf

Thanks,
Iztok Jeras

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for some examples to start working from , you should go to this three.js tutorials site : http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js .
There is a lot of examples and the ones you might be interested of are :

- [the tranlucence](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Translucence.html)
- [the reflection](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Reflection.html)
- [the refraction](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Refraction.html)
- [some bubble effect](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Bubble.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: @WestLangley : Ain't he asking :"I would be glad if I could get a reasonably simple example to start working from." and "Therefore I was looking for: translucency, reflections, rotating an object with a fixed light source, visible edges." ? So what would the response be like? Plus I don't see what rule I broke